# Is using the result of new char[] or malloc to casted float * is UB (strict aliasing violation)?

Tags: c++, malloc, language-lawyer, strict-aliasing, object-lifetime

Which code of these has UB (specifically, which violates strict aliasing rule)?

```
void a() {
    std::vector<char> v(sizeof(float));
    float *f = reinterpret_cast<float *>(v.data());
    *f = 42;
}

void b() {
    char *a = new char[sizeof(float)];
    float *f = reinterpret_cast<float *>(a);
    *f = 42;
}

void c() {
    char *a = new char[sizeof(float)];
    float *f = new(a) float;
    *f = 42;
}

void d() {
    char *a = (char*)malloc(sizeof(float));
    float *f = reinterpret_cast<float *>(a);
    *f = 42;
}

void e() {
    char *a = (char*)operator new(sizeof(float));
    float *f = reinterpret_cast<float *>(a);
    *f = 42;
}
```

I ask this, because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46960015/efficiently-generating-byte-buffer-without-breaking-strict-aliasing) question.

I think, that `d` doesn't have UB (or else `malloc` would be useless in C++). And because of this, it seems logical, that `b`, `c` & `e`  doesn't have it either. Am I wrong somewhere? Maybe `b` is UB, but `c` is not?

Comment: aliasing is usually a problem only when you continue to use both pointers after the alias. I wouldn't think any of those generate a warning.

Comment: IIRC, the `char` types are exempt from the strict aliasing issue. Alignment is still a problem, though.

Comment: I think @GarrGodfrey is pointing out that all modern compilers have consistently predictable Behavior in the scenarios in the OP. And that strict aliasing violations issues only really kick-in when Load-Hit-Stores might come into play. But relying on this would not be future proof in any way.

Comment: @molbdnilo: you can use `char *` to examine any value. The opposite is not necessarily true.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46909105/existence-of-objects-created-in-c-functions

Comment: @geza Oh, right. So IRI, then.

Comment: I believe they are all invalid: everything except `c()` is invalid because you need to use placement `new` to create an object, not just `reinterpret_cast`, and all of `a()` through `c()` are invalid due to alignment. I’m not that confident about either of those, though. A valid version would be `void f() { char *a = (char*)malloc(sizeof(float)); float *f = new(a) float; *f = 42; }`; both `malloc` and the standard library’s `operator new` are guaranteed to have enough alignment.

Comment: "_else malloc would be useless in C++_" malloc is useless. Std C++ is broken and useless! (in a strict interpretation, if you refuse the evidence showing that some chapters are garbage and dismissable)

Comment: @curiousguy: Maybe it's the language barrier, but I don't quite understand you. Do you mean that "malloc is useless" is too harsh? Re-reading my question, yes, I agree on that. Not useless, but very cumbersome to use. Maybe I should delete that paragraph, as the question stands by itself without it.

Comment: @geza you mean that a `char` expression can be used to examine any value. The `char` expression might be obtained by dereferencing a `char *` expression, although there are other means.  A `char *` expression cannot be used directly to examine any value.

Comment: @geza Either you dismiss some std sections as being BS, or you have to accept that no historically accepted C/C++ code using malloc is valid. C/C++ is dead!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Preamble: *storage* and *objects* are different concepts in C++. *Storage* refers to memory space,  and *objects* are entities with lifetimes, that may be created and destroyed within a piece of storage. Storage may be re-used for hosting multiple objects over time.  All objects require storage, but there can be storage with no objects in it.

---

**c** is correct. Placement-new is one of the valid methods of creating an object in storage (C++14 [intro.object]/1), even if there were pre-existing objects in that storage. The old objects are implicitly destroyed by the re-use of the storage, and this is perfectly fine so long as they did not have non-trivial destructors ([basic.life]/4). `new(a) float;` creates an object of type `float` and dynamic storage duration within the existing storage ([expr.new]/1).

**d** and **e** are undefined by omission in the current object model rules: the effect of accessing memory via a glvalue expression is only defined when that expression refers to an object; and not for when the expression refers to storage containing no objects. (Note: please do not leave non-constructive comments regarding the obvious inadequacy of the existing definitions).

This does not mean "malloc is useless"; the effect of `malloc` and `operator new` is to obtain *storage*. Then you can create objects in the storage and use those objects.  This is in fact exactly how standard allocators, and the `new` expression, work.

**a** and **b** are strict aliasing violations: a glvalue of type `float` is used to access objects of incompatible type `char`. ([basic.lval]/10)

---

[There is a proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0593r1.html) which would make all of the cases well-defined (other than the alignment of **a** mentioned below): under this proposal, using `*f` implicitly creates an object of that type in the location, with some caveats.

---

Note: There is no alignment problem in cases **b** through **e**, because the new-expression and `::operator new` are guaranteed to allocate storage correctly aligned for any type ([new.delete.single]/1).

However, in the case of `std::vector<char>`, even though the standard specifies that `::operator new` be called to obtain storage, the standard doesn't require that the first vector element be placed in the first byte of that storage; e.g. the vector could decide to allocate 3 extra bytes on the front and use those for some book-keeping.

Comment: @T.C. thanks, updated my answer according to your comment. Are there any existing implementations that do add padding?

Comment: I don't think so (an implementation could conceivably stash size/capacity in the allocated block or something, but that seems unlikely to be beneficial), but we are in language-lawyer land :)

Comment: `a` and `b` are also OK under P0593R1's rules (modulo the theoretical alignment issue with `a`). A `float` object would spring into existence just in time for the write to be well-defined.

Comment: @T.C. I'm not clear about that from the proposal: it says objects can spring into existence where there were no "real" objects  but in the (a), (b) cases the storage does include real `char` objects already. The example in section 1.2 of the proposal only works in space that was allocated by an external API (and therefore could be storage with no real objects yet). But the example in 2.3 does allow an `int` to spring where there were real `char`s , it seems to me that further clarification will be required. (E.g. if you spring an `int` on a `short` buffer, can you still access the `short`s ?)

Comment: The proposed rule, which is in 2.2, is quite simple. Implicit-lifetime objects are sprung into existence as necessary to give the program defined behavior. In your int/short example, you'd be able to write to the `short`s (springing up new `short` objects just prior to the write) but not read from them (because any new `short` object sprung up would have indeterminate values).

Comment: So char* pBuffer = new char[16]; float* pFloat = (pFloat*)pBuffer; *pFloat = 7  is strict aliasing violation? But char* pBuffer = new char[16]; float* pFloat = (pFloat*)pBuffer; new (pFloat) float; *pFloat = 7; is OK? In other words aliasing the char buffer with a float pointer, but using placement new at that memory position I can then alias and access with a float pointer?

Answer (score 1):

Even though it's a discussion between the OP and I that spawned this question, I'll still put my interpretation here.

I believe that all of these save for `c()` contain strict aliasing violations as formally defined by the standard.

I base this on section 1.8.1 of the [standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)

> ... An object is created by a definition (3.1), by a new-expression (5.3.4)
>   or by the implementation (12.2) when needed. ...

`reinterpret_cast<>`ing memory does not fall under either of these cases.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` never creates a new object, but it doesn't mean that that the resulting pointer or reference is always unsafe to use. If the result is of a type that is allowed to alias the original object, it's fine. For example, you can reinterpret a `unsigned int` as an `int`. No `int` object was ever created, but using the result of the cast is well defined. You are legally using an `int` despite no `int` ever being created. The question here is if you can use the array of chars as a `float`. [Type aliasing](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing)

Comment: I believe your conclusion is correct, but I don't believe the passage you provided explains why.

Comment: Well, I was going to point to 3.10.10, but that only applies if you can establish that there is no `float` object currently residing at that memory location. So I still feel the core reason is 1.8.1.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux The newest c++ standard does not say that signed and unsigned can be aliased, but that similar values have the same representation. So we can expect in a near future that compilers does not any more consider that a pointer to an unsigned int alias a pointer to int.

Answer (score 1):

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast):

> Type aliasing
>
> Whenever an attempt is made to read or modify the stored value of an
>   object of type DynamicType through a glvalue of type AliasedType, the
>   behavior is undefined unless one of the following is true:
>
> - AliasedType and DynamicType are similar.
> - AliasedType is the (possibly cv-qualified) signed or unsigned variant of DynamicType.
> - AliasedType is std::byte, (since C++17)char, or unsigned char: this permits examination of the object representation of any object as
>     an array of bytes.
>
> Informally, two types are similar if, after stripping away cv-qualifications at
>   every level (but excluding anything inside a function type), they are the same 
>   type.
>
> For example: [...some examples...]

Also [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category):

> a glvalue is an expression whose evaluation determines the identity of
>   an object, bit-field, or function;

The above is relevant for all example except (c). Types are neither similar nor signed/unsigned variants. Also the `AliasedType` (the type you cast to) is neither of `char`, `unsigned char` or `std::byte`. Hence all of them (but c) exhibit undefined behaviour.

**Disclaimer:** First of all cppreference is not an official reference, but only the standard is. Secondly, unfortunately I am not even 100% certain if my interpretation of what I read on cppreference is correct.

Comment: Case c has no reinterpret_cast.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux is `new(a) float;` not a glvalue? I am not sure... I dont mention reinterpret_cast

Comment: @tobi303 See my answer for this, section 1.8.1 establishes that a new expression creates the object, making it a glvalue.

Comment: You mention reinterpret_cast in the url in the first line of your answer and the first citation block quote's it's documentation.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux strict aliasing is explained there and I think the explanation is more general and not only refers to reinterpret casting.

Comment: In (c), `new(a) float;` creates an object whose DynamicType is `float`